# iOS browser - iFrame jumps to top when changing css or content using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iframe, browser

This problem seems to have been around forever. Under some specific circumstances, iOS browsers surface this frustrating bug.

**The issue:**

If you have a web page which contains an iFrame and you are modifying the iFrames content document programmatically, the iFrame will jump to the top of the page.  However, this only happens if the page, before the DOM manipulation, is beyond some height, typically this seems to be a length greater than twice the length of the viewport.

This issue appears regardless of whether you are modifying the DOM structure or changing style properties.

This bug is only present on iOS, including the latest release as of this time (9.2)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Problem description:**

The issue appears to be that browsers in iOS (including chrome as it uses [the same rendering engine](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/overview)) are not correctly calculating the height of iFrames, this is causing jumping behaviour when repaints occur on the browser.

**The solutions:**

**Solution A:** Adding the following code to the iFrame stylesheet resolves the issue in most cases, though scrolling for drag events etc may present problems with this approach.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

**Solution B:**
When the iFrame has rendered everything, you should calculate the height of the iFrame content then set that height value explicitly on the iFrame element using an inline style in javascript. This value needs to be updated as content is modified or added in the iFrame, you must ensure the height is always correct to prevent the jumping from reoccurring.

This presents challenges when dealing with third party plugins and widgets which alter the page with no obvious callbacks. The best case for dealing with this for now is the use of [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Wow, this did the trick for me (Solution A). I've been searching for months. Thanks!

Comment: Solution A worked for me too. All three styles are important to apply.

Comment: When I do this it stops the jumping, however it causes photos below the fold on an iPhone to not display. I've tried adding -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); as research on the forum say this solves the issue but for me it doesn't. Anyone solved something like this?

Comment: Could you show a test site which exhibits the issue?

Comment: I've had a quick look and you're using an old jQuery lazy loading library, this is almost certainly the problem. I expect it's not detecting that you are scrolling so the assets remain unloaded.

Comment: I've updated to v1.7.5 but it doesn't seem to have had an effect, cleared cache as well. I've tried this with and without -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);

Comment: I've sorted this now. For me it was an actual issue with Lazy load. To solve my issue I told Lazy Load to actually load the images first, this can be done by setting 'threshold : 400' or a larger number if you have more images to load below the fold. For me I only had a few and therefore I feel the load time isn't compromised as the images are also small in file size.

Comment: Thanks @Yoda, I was trying to resolve this issue from last 3 days.. Finally you help to get rid from the issue.

Comment: Is there a bug filed with Webkit that we should follow/upvote? I did some searching and couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

If you use some code like this

```
var doc = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(data);
doc.close();
```

Try to remove `doc.close();` It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Ionic 3, it can install the native keyboard and disable the autofocus on input, with the next code

import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

this.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/blob/0691ad09f5b03861d73ca7c228e4efd2d691d5a3/www/ios/keyboard.js#L90
That feature is gone. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I solved it with this CSS in the iframe style sheet (logically I had access to the embedded web!).

I had a problem with the width and I solved it by adding in my javascript:

```
var x = screen.width; 
$('body').css('width',x+'px');
```